# Pivot table value to appear inside shape

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I would like to link a shape to a pivot table value. I get the following error when I try to do that.

I click on the shape, then I go to the formula bar and click on the pivot cell which I need to be shown in the shape. I click OK, normally it used to work in the past. I do not understand why I am getting this error.[screenshot of the error along with the formula bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/inDi3.png)

Comment: Replace the GETPIVOTDATA formula with the actual cell reference, including sheet name.

Comment: Thanks, it works. Do you know why the GETPIVOTDATA is not working?

Comment: You can only use a range as the link, not a function.